# How can I make bootstrap rows closer together?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a footer with bootstrap rows and columns, and I want to make the footer smaller by reducing the space between rows. I've tried changing the margin and padding of the rows to no avail.

```
<footer class="footerClass">
        <div class="row footerRow">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <b>Content</b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row footerRow">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><a href="mailto:Content">Content</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row footerRow">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <p><a href=""><b>Content</b></a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><a href=""><b>Content</b></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row footerRow table-condensed">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><a href="www.Content.org">www.Content.org</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Bootstrap does not have any spacing between rows by default. The spacing is coming from the `margin-bottom` of your `p` tags.

Comment: OP please upload a basic minimal example of your code...  @j08691 you're really fast :)

Comment: Not the proper way to represent bootstrap code..

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your additional classes have caused the spacing issues that you're seeing. I would rewrite your footer in the following way to see if it resolves your issue:

```
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <b>Content</b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><a href="mailto:Content">Content</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <p><a href=""><b>Content</b></a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><a href=""><b>Content</b></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><a href="www.Content.org">www.Content.org</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</footer>
```

Also, typically when using bootstrap grids, your column width would add up to 12 for each row. This may have been intentional.

I use the following classes to handle vertical spacing in my designs:

```
.voffset  { margin-top: 2px; }
.voffset1 { margin-top: 5px; }
.voffset2 { margin-top: 10px; }
.voffset3 { margin-top: 15px; }
.voffset4 { margin-top: 30px; }
.voffset5 { margin-top: 40px; }
.voffset6 { margin-top: 60px; }
.voffset7 { margin-top: 80px; }
.voffset8 { margin-top: 100px; }
.voffset9 { margin-top: 150px; }
.boffset  { margin-bottom: 2px; }
.boffset1 { margin-bottom: 5px; }
.boffset2 { margin-bottom: 10px; }
.boffset3 { margin-bottom: 15px; } 
.boffset4 { margin-bottom: 30px; }
.boffset5 { margin-bottom: 40px; }
.boffset6 { margin-bottom: 60px; }
.boffset7 { margin-bottom: 80px; }
.boffset8 { margin-bottom: 100px; }
.boffset9 { margin-bottom: 150px; }
```

Comment: I guess you need to wrap rows into the block with `.container` or `.container-fluid` class.

Comment: Depending on the intent, a container or container-fluid class would probably be necessary, but not necessary to troubleshoot his issue.

Comment: I fear that the row without the container will cause the horizontal scrolling. It's no good style. `Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.` http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro

Comment: Edited answer to include container class! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The minimum width of the media query "col-md-xx" is 992px , Try to apply class with "col-sm-xx". May be You are asking this.